# How can you show that $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r) \leftrightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ is not a tautology?

Tags: logic, symbolic-computation

Obviously, $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ due to Hypothetical Syllogism, but how about the converse?
How can I disprove the statement?

Comment: A truth table would suffice.

Comment: The converse is not true consider $(p,q,r)=(0,1,0)$

Comment: It's not a tautology; you cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a tautology; so you cannot prove it.

Consider $p$ and $r$ as true but $q$ as false.  Thence $p\to r$ is true, but $p\to q$ is false (and hence $(p\to q)\land(q\to r)$ too).